# R statistic problem, t test will not perform on list elements

Tags: r, statistics

I have a list that contains the number of cells pre and post treatment. I have a,b,c elements in the list and each elements has a pre and a post column that contains data on number of cells.

When I try to perform a t-test, I get the following error:

Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I am confused why this error is occurring, any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

``Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") :

`enter code here`  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

`enter code here`> traceback()

`enter code here`10: t.test.default(as.numeric(d[i, grep("pct_rep", colnames(d))]),
alternative = "two")

`enter code here`9: t.test(as.numeric(d[i, grep("pct_rep", colnames(d))]), alternative = "two") at #1

`enter code here`8: ifelse(sum(!is.na(d[i, grep("pct_rep", colnames(d))])) > 1, t.test(as.numeric(d[i,
grep("pct_rep", colnames(d))]), alternative = "two")$p.value,
NA) at #1

`enter code here`7: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

`enter code here`6: lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)

`enter code here`5: sapply(rownames(d), function(i) ifelse(sum(!is.na(d[i, grep("pct_rep",
colnames(d))])) > 1, t.test(as.numeric(d[i, grep("pct_rep",
colnames(d))]), alternative = "two")$p.value, NA)) at #1

`enter code here`4: analyze(norm = norm, thresh = thresh, nthresh = nthresh) at #1

`enter code here`3: assign(name, obj, envir = .GlobalEnv) at #1

`enter code here`2: ass("data", analyze(norm = norm, thresh = thresh, nthresh = nthresh)) at #1

`enter code here`1: RUN_DNA(12, norm = F, thresh = F, tag = "raw")

Comment: you will need to be a bit clearer in your question. you are talking about a list, then show a table? form which is 4x4 with above it ```A-------- B--------- C```, can you clearify the list structure? Also you show an error, could you show the code you used that created the error?

Comment: Could you post sample data and the code that is producing the error?

Comment: Sorry, the table was just a representation of the values in each element of the list. So i have a list with a,b, and c elements in it. Each element has a pre and a post column with number of cells in them. The code that is giving me the error is:  t.test.default(as.numeric(d[i, grep("pct_rep", colnames(d))]),
        alternative = "two")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to create some data that resembles yours:

```
set.seed(42)
pre <- rpois(30, 5)
post <- pre - rpois(30, 1)
group <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each=10)
alldata <- data.frame(group, pre, post)
dta <- split(alldata[, -1], alldata$group)
str(dta)
# List of 3
#  $ a:'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ pre : int [1:10] 8 9 4 7 6 5 6 3 6 6
#   ..$ post: int [1:10] 6 7 3 6 6 3 6 3 4 5
#  $ b:'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ pre : int [1:10] 5 6 9 3 5 9 10 2 5 5
#   ..$ post: int [1:10] 4 5 9 0 4 6 8 1 2 4
#  $ c:'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ pre : int [1:10] 8 3 11 9 2 5 4 8 5 7
#   ..$ post: int [1:10] 8 3 10 7 2 3 3 8 5 6
```

Now run paired t-test on pre and post:

```
lapply(dta, function(x) t.test(x$pre, x$post, paired=TRUE))
# $a
# 
#   Paired t-test
# 
# data:  x$pre and x$post
# t = 3.9727, df = 9, p-value = 0.003241
# alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.473637 1.726363
# sample estimates:
# mean difference 
#             1.1
```

I have not shown the results for b and c.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed post and it helped. The main issue with my data was that I had some 0 values in some of the replicates so the mean could not be calculated to eventually perform the t test. You were able to replicate the data correctly and this helped me get to the solution. Thank you!